# Powershell 2.0 Issue with script to Restore folders from backup location

Tags: powershell

I have a backup Folder F:\DATA\01172014 - this folder has five sub dirs \Folder1, \Folder2, Folder3, Folder4, Folder5

F:\DATA\01172014..
..\Folder1
..\Folder2
..\Folder3
..\Folder4
..\Folder5

I want to copy the the folders 1 through 5  to the E:\Main location overwriting the existing folders

E:\Main
..\Folder1
..\Folder2
..\Folder3
..\Folder4
..\Folder5

My problem is when I run the script  it finds the 01172014 folder and copy's it to the E:\Main as the same name and does not overwrite the old folders

E:\Main
..\01172014
..\Folder1
..\Folder2
..\Folder3
\Folder4
..\Folder5

My question is what am I missing

Here is my code I am using :-

```
Get-ChildItem -Path F:\DATA -r | 
Where-object {$_.PSIscontainer -and (($_.lastwritetime.date -eq ((get-date).adddays(-1)).date))}  |
% { Copy-Item  $_.fullName -destination E:\Main\ -force -R -whatif}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to copy the date-stamped folder and contents, and it is.

Try something like this instead which will copy the contents of the date-stamped folder and its sub-folders, but not the folder itself (`-Container` switch retains the structure):

```
$BackupDir = Get-ChildItem ("F:\DATA\" + (((get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMddyyyy"))))|%{$_.FullName}  

Copy-Item $BackupDir -Destination ("E:\Main\" + (Split-Path $BackupDir -leaf)) -R -Container -Force -WhatIf
```